# Jinja2 can not read multi line property values

Tags: jinja2

This is the content of  **my.j2** template file

```
mvalue ={{ mvalue }}
svalue={{ svalue }}
```

and This is the content of the **a.env** file  from which template files will read the value

```
mvalue= first line
second line
svalue=singleline
```

Please see the output after running the j2cli 0.3.1-0 process ( Im running it on fish terminal)

```
 j2cli 0.3.1-0 my.j2 a.env
    mvalue =first line
    svalue=singleline
```

As you can see  *mvalue* is getting only  the First line as value. It's not getting the *second line*.

How can I read multi line values in j2 files?

Comment: What's `j2`? There are multiple command line utilities using the Jinja2 library, I know `j2cli` and `jinja2`. I have no idea what `j2` is though. Also, none of your files have remotely YAML syntax. Are you expecting them to be YAML?

Comment: in my ssytem j2 was j2cli 0.3.1-0, Jinja2 2.10 ( update the question with this info). To be honest, I do not know whether it was to be YAML. Existing a.env file was in the key=value format  where value was in one line but for my changes the value can be in multi lines

Answer (score 1):

`.env` files use shell syntax to define environment variables, so you should do this:

```
mvalue='first line
second line'
svalue=singleline
```

If you want to use YAML syntax, use

```
j2 my.j2 a.yml
```

With `a.yml` being

```
mvalue: |-
  first line
  second line
svalue: singleline
```

Comment: Changing to .yml is not under my control becuase it has datas of some other people also. But the other one ( quotes) did not work for me. It still read only  the 1st line /usr/local/bin/j2 my.j2 a.env
mvalue = 'first line
svalue=singleline~

Comment: Okay, seems like I assumed too much. What you want to do is simply not possible in `.env`. The [actual parser](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli/blob/master/j2cli/context.py#L113) does not support escaping, quoting or anything.

Comment: Thanks. On another note,  I have hard time in understanding following lambda from the env parse of jni_cl2.  Could you please describe it.        data = filter(
            lambda l: len(l) == 2 ,
            (
                list(map(
                    str.strip,
                    line.split('=', 1)
                ))
                for line in data_string.split("\n"))

Comment: The lambda filters out any lines which do not have a `=` in it because `len(l)` would be `1` for them. `l` is taken from the list generated in the second argument of `filter`, which basically splits each line by its first `=` while removing spaces around both items.